# Uncaught ReferenceError: Stage is not defined using EaselJS

Tags: html, createjs, easeljs

I'm setting up a quick little test to start digging into EaselJS but I'm getting this error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: Stage is not defined`. I'm unsure as to why Stage is not defined as I checked easeljs-NEXT.combined.js for the Stage method and it's definitely in there. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Easel Intro</title>
        <!-- EaselJS Library -->
        <script src="js/vendor/easeljs-NEXT.combined.js"></script>

        <script>
        var stage;
        var text;
        var logo;

            function init()
            {
                stage = new Stage(document.getElementById("canvas"));

                logo = new Bitmap("img/HTML5_Logo_64.png");
                logo.regX = logo.image.width * 0.5;
                logo.regY = logo.image.height * 0.5;
                stage.addChild(logo);

                text = new Text("Text rendered on the canvas.", "36px Arial", "#666");
                text.x = 100;
                text.y = 100;
                stage.addChild(text);

                stage.update();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="580"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix all CreateJS classes with `createjs.`.

```
new createjs.Stage("canvas");
```

This goes for all items in your example: Stage, Bitmap, and Text.

There may be out-of-date documentation or examples out there, since early versions (2011 or so) didn't have a namespace.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I was operating from some old examples.